# Downloading multiple files with ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: ios, file, download, request, asihttprequest

I'm working on a project where I need to have 3 different .plist files downloaded for a server but I only manage to get one of them downloaded. Anyone know how to get all 3 of them downloaded? I'm using ASIHTTPRequest. 
Mycode:

```
- (void)downloadPlist {
NSLog(@"Download in progress...");


progressView.alpha = 1.0;


// Here we're downloading the .plist file from a server to the app's Documents Directory.
// Create file manager
fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

// Point to Document directory
documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory()
                      stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];


documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];

filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"example1.plist"];
filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"example2.plist"];
filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"example3.plist"];




// files from server.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myWeb.com/example1.plist"];
NSURL *url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myWeb.com/example2.plist"];
NSURL *url2 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myWeb.com/example3.plist"];



request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url1];
request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url2];
[request setShowAccurateProgress:YES];
[request setDownloadDestinationPath:filePath];
[request setDownloadProgressDelegate:progressView];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

}

I think I'm on the right track but not sure... cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have used same variable names in several places to get three files. First variable is "filePath"

Change the variables to separate names for e.g. like this,

```
filePath1 = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"example1.plist"];
filePath2 = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"example2.plist"];
filePath3 = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"example3.plist"];
```

Same is with "request" variable??

Make correction for e.g. like this,

```
request1 = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
request2 = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url1];
request3 = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url2];
```

Or if you want to have only 1 request object then maybe try loop over all 3 urls and assign request one by one.
Make sure you supply different filePaths in your loop

```
[request setDownloadDestinationPath:filePath**{N}**];
```

Comment: Was just about to post mine lol. But yeah, simple mistake by overwriting the entity. humayun idea of a loop is a better idea. Maybe set up a NSArray with NSDictionaries to hold url and filepath together. Then loop that.